# Copy Row if criteria is met to a new sheet

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to copy and paste rows into a new sheet if the criteria is met.

I have the code and it somewhat works. It copies any row in column "N" if it has "FEH" and pastes into a new worksheet labeled "FEH." However, each time it copies and pastes the row into the new worksheet it opens up a dialog box that says "Updating Values: Name of folder where workbook is saved" The box looks like a save as dialog box. I have to click cancel or close out of it each and every time (I have included a picture of the dialog box).

[image: I have included a picture of the dialog box]

I found this code from a youtube channel: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qGZQIl9JJk4

I removed two lines that he is using because if I leave those lines the code doesn't stop running.

What do I have to fix in order for this dialog box to not show up?

```
Private Sub CommandButton2_Click()
 a = Worksheets("Invoice").Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
  For i = 2 To a
     If Worksheets("Invoice").Cells(i, "N").Value = "FEH" Then
        Worksheets("Invoice").Rows(i).Copy
        Worksheets("FEH").Activate
        b = Worksheets("FEH").Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
        Worksheets("FEH").Cells(b + 1, 1).Select
        ActiveSheet.Paste
    End If
  Next
End Sub
```

Comment: You have a query or formula or some kind of link with a workbook/worksheet reference that excel cannot locate. Check youtube for 'removing missing links'.

Comment: If you are interested in values only, then you could paste them (with PasteSpecial method or exploiting Value property) and avoid the dialog box issue